# Store a TimeSpan in a Windows Phone 8 app local database

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am building an Windows Phone 8 app that uses a local database. This all works fine, but I have a `TimeSpan` value which I would like to save in the database. But the app crashes when it tries to create the database with the following code:

```
private TimeSpan _startTime;
[Column]
public TimeSpan StartTime
{
    get { return _startTime; }
    set
    {
        if (_startTime != value)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanging("StartTime");
            _startTime = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("StartTime");
        }
    }
}
```

So I changed the second line to `[Column(DbType = "DATETIME")]` which works fine. But this is not what I want. Now it stores a `DATETIME` while I only want to store the time. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

The error (in Dutch):

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Data.Internal.ni.dll
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: Het opgegeven gegevenstype is ongeldig. [ Data type (if known) = TIME ]
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.CompileQueryPlan()
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteCommand(String command)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.CreateDatabase()
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.CreateDatabase()
   at MyWPApp.Controller..ctor()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Good way to store and read timestamp in Windows Phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079773/good-way-to-store-and-read-timestamp-in-windows-phone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution proposed [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5b897353-597e-44f5-a2a2-79f7d0cd9ed7/store-timespan-in-compact-edition?forum=sqlce) is to convert the `TimeSpan` yourself into a `datetime` object or `varchar`. Personally I would recommend to save it as a numeric type, like integer, use the seconds for example as the unit of measurement.

You could do something like this to do the conversion without effort. The `StartTime` is  saved to the DB, while you can use `StartTimeTS` in your software:

```
[Column]
public int StartTime
{
    get
    {
        return this.StartTimeTS.TotalSeconds;
    }
    set
    {
        this.StartTimeTS = new TimeSpan(0, 0, value);
    }
}

private TimeSpan _startTime;
public TimeSpan StartTimeTS
{
    get { return _startTime; }
    set
    {
        if (_startTime != value)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanging("StartTime");
            _startTime = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("StartTime");
        }
    }
}
```

Also, does your datatype in .NET really need to be `TimeSpan` and not just `DateTime`? The name seems to suggest that.

Comment: It doesn't NEED to be `TimeSpan`, but the date is never used, so I think `TimeSpan` would be cleaner. I will try your solution.

Comment: @LeonHooijer: I personally think the `int` solution would probably be the best if you are really talking about `TimeSpan`.